# Question about a proof: $U$ maximal among non-finitely generated ideals of $R$, then $U$ is a prime ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Question: The following problem has been asked and answered many times on MSE, but there was one proof I had a question about (though I can't find the proof now).  The question is:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and let $U$ be maximal among non-finitely generated ideals of $R$.  Prove $U$ is a prime ideal.

The proof I saw went like this: "Suppose $U$ is not prime.  Then, there exists $a,b\in R$ such that $a,b\notin U, ab\in U$.  Consider ideal $J$ defined to be $J=U+(a)$.  Since $U$ is not finitely generated, neither is $J$.  Also, $J$ is proper in $R$, because if $J=R$, then $a\in U$, a contradiction.  So, $J$ is a proper ideal strictly greater than $U$ that is not finitely generated.  A contradiction, so $U$ is prime"

I had two questions about the proof.  First, why would $J$ necessarily be an ideal, and second, how does $J\neq R\implies a\in U$?

Thank you!

Comment: Since $U$ and $(a)$ are both ideals, so is their sum; you should be able to prove that. The second is, I think, a typo: you get $b\in U$ if $J=R$: for $1\in J$, so $1=u+ra$ for some $u\in U$ and $r\in R$. Multiplying by $b$ you get $b = ub+rab\in U$, since $ub\in U$ and $ab\in U$ hence $rab\in U$.

Comment: Ah, so because of that, this proof is broken, right?  I don't think there would be a way to save it from there.

Comment: No, you can still proceed to conclude that $J\neq R$. I'd be more wary about the claim that $J$ must be non-finitely generated, as it is perfectly possible for a finitely generated ideal to contain a non-finitely generated ideal.

Comment: There is a typo, but the argument is severely broken and the proof is wrong. To begin with, $U+(a)$ must *necessarily* be finitely generated, since it's an ideal that properly contains $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. If $I$ and $J$ are ideals, then so is $I+J= \{x+y\mid x\in I, y\in J\}$. Indeed, it is nonempty since $I$ and $J$ are nonempty; if $x_1,x_2\in I$ and $y_1,y_2\in J$, then $(x_1+y_1)-(x_2+y_2) = (x_1-x_2) + (y_1-y_2)\in I+J$, so $I+J$ is an additive subgroup. And given $x\in I$, $y\in J$, and $r\in R$, we have $r(x+y) = (rx)+(ry) \in I+J$. This also works in a noncommutative ring (and for one sided ideals), as you also have $(x+y)r = (xr) + (yr)\in I+J$. For the case at hand, $U$ is an ideal and $(a)$ is an ideal, so $U+(a)$ is necessarily an ideal.

   In fact, $I+J$ is the smallest ideal that contains both $I$ and $J$.
2. This is, I suspect, a typo. Suppose that $ab\in U$. If $a\in U$, we are done. If $a\notin U$, then we look at $J$. If $J=R$, then $1\in J= U+(a)$, so there exists $u\in U$, $r\in R$ such that $1=u+ra$. Multiplying by $b$ we get $b = ub + r(ab)$. Since $u,ab\in U$, then $ub+r(ab)\in U$, and so we get that $b\in U$, and we are done. Thus, we are reduced to the case where $J\neq R$, $a\notin U$.

In this case, $J$ is a proper ideal that properly contains $U$. Now, we need to show that $J$ is non-finitely generated to reach a contradiction. I think this proof is a little too cavalier in the assertion that this is clear, though. It is clear that if $J$ is finitely generated, then you can find a finite set of elements $u_1,\ldots,u_n\in U$ such that $u_1,\ldots,u_n,a$ together generate $J$, but it is not clear to me that this implies that $U$ would then be finitely generated...

Comment: Actually, it is *obvious* that $J$ is finitely generated, because it properly contains $U$.

Comment: @egreg: If you are trying to reach a contradiction from the assumption that $ab\in U$ but $a\notin U$ and $b\notin U$, then you would want to prove that $J$ is an element strictly larger than $U$ in the set in which $U$ Is maximal, so of course one possibility would be to argue that $J$ is non-finitely generated. In fact that is what I am saying: that you need to *prove* it is not finitely generated to reach a contradiction, not just say it off-handedly.

Comment: That's right, but the argument starts off by saying that $J$ is not finitely generated, which is exactly the opposite from what follows from the assumptions.

Comment: @egreg: I think the argument pretends that it is easy to conclude that $J$ Is not finitely genrated from the fact that it contains the non-finitely generated ideal $U$; but that is not a valid implication.  After all, the whole ring is a finitely generated ideal that contains the non-finitely generated ideal $U$.

Comment: Ah, okay, so the proof essentially brushes off and claims that $J$ is not finitely generated, but this would need to be shown.  I know egreg said this "might" be able to be done, but I'm not seeing how we could get to that conclusion here, so maybe it is just completely broken (more than it already is) after all.

Comment: @user7238: Yes, I don't see how to conclude it easily; as I said, if you assume $J$ is finitely generated, you get a family $u_1+r_1a,\ldots,u_n+r_na$ of elements that generate, which means $u_1,\ldots,u_n,a$ generate $J$, but this does not mean that $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ necessarily generate $U$ (which would contradict that $U$ is finitely generated). I don't think you can just say "it is not finitely generated, because $U$ is not finitely generated." You need to *prove* it is not finitley generated, and I don't see how the fact that $U$ Is not gives it to you here.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Besides, who wrote the argument seems to ignore the fact that a non finitely generated ideal *must* be proper.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo, that is $J$ is proper because $b\notin J$ (not $a$). However the “proof” is completely wrong.

Indeed, it follows from maximality of $U$ that $J=U+(a)$ *is* finitely generated, because it properly contains $U$. One *might* prove that it is not finitely generated in order to find a contradiction, but the given argument fails to address this.